# Android Studio Not Opening on Windows 10

Tags: android-studio, windows-10

I installed the Android Studio on Windows 10 and I've been trying to open it but it keeps giving error.

[image: error screeshot].

Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: Have you tried well, reading that error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install the Java Development Toolkit, or point to one that you already installed.

(http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/index.html)